# ionic archive ios plugins not found

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, testflight

I'm trying to archive my IOS app (ionic app) and test it on device with Xcode.

When I run my app directly on device, everything is fine. I tried both debug and release scheme.

When I archive my app then upload it to a device with Xcode or via Testflight, I got no error, but I think some plugins are missing because app is broken.

unfortunately I can't debug JavaScript on this archived app so i'm not sure of the error.

all plugins are well listed when i run `cordova plugin list` and all are in `plugins/ios.json` file.

Everything is fine on Android

Any idea ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I update my cordova version and delete `plugins/ios.json` file.

Now it's work !